# The Ethics of Selling SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

So this might not belong here as it's not a tech question, but unsure if it belongs in meta... I'm sure if so a helpful admin will let me know.

So, here's my question - am I the only one who suffers a little ethical cringe every time I have to try and talk up SharePoint Online to a client?

Since I started using/supporting it, I can honestly say I've never used a more troublesome piece of software since the days of owning an Amiga 1200. The lack of control over timer jobs, inability to check ULS logs, random bugs that Microsoft don't document (much less admit to being there), inadequate provision of up to date documentation (for anything complex, any time I try to find a fix the most relevant docs are always the SharePoint 2010/2013 ones), the need to pay for an overly expensive Azure tenant to run managed code... I could go on.

I feel like I'm having to polish turds all the time now, in that I have to go to clients and make all sorts of promises, talking up a product I have very little faith in for anything other than the most basic intranet applications.

I feel Microsoft are making lots of promises of features that simply aren't being delivered - or at least, they're making the promises and releasing poor versions of them and letting the user base work out the bugs before they fix them (yes, I know that's standard for MS, but still).

Surely I'm not the only one?

Comment: These concerns are of course an aside to the general ethical unease I have about cloud services period. I don't like the idea of centralising control over computing power to a lesser number of providers, despite the technical benefits, but that's an entirely different discussion.

Comment: I don't understand why you feel you need to "have to try and talk up SharePoint Online" to your clients. They pay you to give them accurate advice, so give it to them.

Comment: Because going to a client and saying 'well, it's good at some things but here's a list of all the problems' is hardly conducive to winning work...

Answer (score 2):

I share your pain. I never recommend SharePoint Online unless it serves a specific business purpose, and I get really annoyed with Microsoft Salespeople for convincing existing SharePoint On-Premise customers to go to O365 just to push more licenses.

Comment: I've yet to see a specific business purpose that SPO actually fills. It's fine for SMEs who just need some basic intranet and document storage, but for anything enterprise-grade I'd avoid it like the plague. I must say tho, the MS support is actually quite decent (at least if you can use Premier).

Comment: Yeah; neither have I. :)

Comment: @ThomasGass I've had nothing but horrible experiences with MS support.  I jump through flaming hoops to avoid contacting them.  Granted, we don't pay for the premier support.

Comment: There is a massive difference between Professional and Premier I've found. Professional I feel is mainly there for users and smacks of a call-scripted SD with some sort of KB, but Premier have more time, resources and skill. Seems to be some dialog between them and the product/service teams as well.